# Discord Bot Webhook can iplogger people on discord

Tags: discord

I want to know if someone knows or can create a discord bot that when verifying your role on discord the bot sent you a dm and that dm leads to a web page that the web is open with my ip:port and the people who are verified on the page send me their ip to a my Webhook.

Comment: Any malicious link on discord remains unsafe and it is very well possible that you were IP grabbed at that Instance and they even tried to access your sensitive data. **Further I would like to clarify that stackoverflow is for some specific questions that we consider to be answerable, you may view a list of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well any website can grab your ip if they want, but don't worry because they can only access your "public ip". And that won't really affect you, the most they can know is which city you are from.

As long as they don't get your "private ip", they can't really do much. And website's cant really access such private info like a private ip

Comment: But really what I would like to achieve is to be able to get the public ip of the others through a link that a bot sends them by dm to verify their role in discord and through a web hook obtain the public ip of who was verified, I could to get to pay if someone manages to create something like that. I have a friend who had it.